# Remove newline between %s in Python

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I'm using Spyder(Python 3.7) and want to write 3 different words in the same line.

I wrote the following code:

```
write("%s%s%s" %(a, b, c)) # where a='aaa', b='bbb', c='ccc'
```

I expected it to show me

```
aaabbbccc
```

But it is showing me

```
aaa

bbb

ccc
```

Is there any invisible `'\n' between %s`? Then how can I remove it? I tried to use `sep='\t'` but this Spyder can't understand sep.

Comment: There is filename. in front of write command.

Comment: Are you *sure* your `a`, `b` and `c` values contain what you expect? Might the newlines be part of the variables, rather than something added by the string formatting?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something else in your code, this definitely works without any `\n`

```py
a = "aaa"

b = "bbb"

c = "ccc"

with open("file.txt","w") as f:
     f.write("%s%s%s"%(a, b, c))
```

"file.txt" is now

```
aaabbbccc
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It works for strings but it isn't for variables. Actually I want to change the strings for every lines. So I should put variables instead of string itself.

Comment: same result with variables, you're definitely doing something else there - post your full program if you can.

Comment: I added the code in an answer. What a simple code, but works in strange way.

Answer (score 0):

I added my full code.

frq, mag, phase are some floating numbers.
filename is just blahblah.txt

I'm sure that there's no new lines if I run this code in python directly, but not in spyder(ver4.0.1). I can't understand what's going on here.

```
P = open('%s' %filename, "a")
P.write("%s%s%s" %(frq, mag, phase))
print("%s%s%s" %(frq, mag, phase))
```

Comment: use PyCharm :D
Sorry, but this looks like an issue with Spider - maybe there's some additional number formatting going on there.